# Travis CI not working for bookdown when using tikz environement

Tags: r, travis-ci, bookdown, tikz

When adding a `tikz` picture environment in `bookdown`, my Travis CI build stops working.

Here is the error.

```
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'magick'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
The command "Rscript -e 'bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd")'" exited with 1.
```

I tried adding the `magick` package to my `DESCRIPTION` file like this:

```
- Imports: 
    bookdown,
    magick
```

or like that

```
- Remotes:
    ropensci/magick
```

My build is still not working.

The easiest way to reproduce the problem is to clone the repo [bookdown_travis](https://github.com/desautm/bookdown_travis). When building the book in RStudio, everything works but I receive an error message on Travis CI.

The problem is in the [07-tikz.Rmd](https://github.com/desautm/bookdown_travis/blob/master/07-tikz.Rmd) file. This file contains a minimal `tikz` example that should be working.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I receive this error message: The command "Rscript -e 'deps <- remotes::dev_package_deps(dependencies = NA);remotes::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE);if (!all(deps$package %in% installed.packages())) { message("missing: ", paste(setdiff(deps$package, installed.packages()), collapse=", ")); q(status = 1, save = "no")}'" failed and exited with 1 during .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the actual build logs](https://travis-ci.com/desautm/bookdown_travis/builds/112950007) we see:

```
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because Magick++ was not found. Try installing:
 - deb: 'libmagick++-dev' (Debian, Ubuntu)
 - rpm: 'ImageMagick-c++-devel' (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 - csw: 'imagemagick_dev' (Solaris)
On MacOS it is recommended to use install ImageMagick-6 from homebrew
with extra support for fontconfig and rsvg rendering:
   brew reinstall imagemagick@6 --with-fontconfig --with-librsvg
For older Ubuntu versions Trusty (14.04) and Xenial (16.04) use our PPA:
   sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:opencpu/imagemagick
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y libmagick++-dev
If Magick++ is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a Magick++.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Since Travis CI uses Xenial, you should use

```
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
    - sourceline: 'ppa:opencpu/imagemagick'
    packages:
    - libmagick++-dev
```

in `.travis.yml`. You will probably have to repeat this process for other packages that require system libraries.

Comment: I did what you just proposed and my buils is still not working. Here is the error message : Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'pdftools'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
The command "Rscript -e 'bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd")'" exited with 1.

Comment: @Marc-AndréDésautels `pdftools` also requires system libraries. The full error message should tell you which one you need.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will look at the full error message.

Answer (score 2):

After the  help from @Ralf Stubner, here is the code I have to add to my `.travis.yml` file to make it work:

```
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
    - sourceline: 'ppa:opencpu/imagemagick'
    - sourceline: 'ppa:opencpu/poppler'
    packages:
    - libmagick++-dev
    - libpoppler-cpp-dev
```